# Return a blank date field if term field is empty

Tags: excel, vba

I'm making an invoice that has a Term field with a drop down list of 30,60. If nothing is chosen, the term field remains empty, which is what I want. For the records, I have the due date equaling the issue date plus the term. How can I get the due date to stay blank if there is no term chosen?

```
Sub RecordOfInvoice()

Dim invno As Long
Dim compname As String
Dim contname As String
Dim po As String
Dim amt As Currency
Dim issdate As Date
Dim duedate As Date
Dim term As Byte
Dim nextrec As Range

invno = Range("G11")
compname = Range("A10")
contname = Range("A11")
po = Range("G15")
amt = Range("G43")
issdate = Range("G13")
term = Range("G17")

**If term = "0" Then duedate = ""**  'This does not work, I want duedate to be empty when posted to the record.
**Else
duedate = dt_issue + term
End If**

Set nextrec = Sheet5.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

nextrec = invno
nextrec.Offset(0, 1) = compname
nextrec.Offset(0, 2) = contname
nextrec.Offset(0, 3) = po
nextrec.Offset(0, 4) = amt
nextrec.Offset(0, 5) = issdate
nextrec.Offset(0, 6) = duedate

End Sub
```

I've tried:

If term = "0" Then duedate = "" 'does not work

If term = "0" Then duedate = term 'returns due date as 12:00:00AM, because duedate would = 0

If term = "0" Then duedate = Sheet5.Range("G2").Clear 'works but creates a problem with nextrec.Offset(0, 6) = duedate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways you could handle this.

**1 Declare the `duedate` as Variant.**

A Variant defines the data type at runtime and, if unassigned, defaults to `Empty`. So your code would be:

```
If term > 0 then duedate = dt_issue + term
```

**2 Apply an If clause to the line that populates the duedate cell:**

```
If term > 0 then
    nextrec.Offset(0, 6) = duedate
End If
```

Comment: The first one just returns a 12:00:00AM, but the second worked like a charm. Thanks.